# Cannot retrieve cookie in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

[image]

I have a cookie that I've set on my site called "your-selected-location".  I'm in FF and using firebug I can see that the cookie is set seemingly correctly and does not expire until next year and is stored in the root "/".  However if I run the following code in very top of my PHP file it does not return the cookie value (which I can see in Firebug)

```
if (isset($_COOKIE[ 'your-selected-location' ]))
    {
        $cookieselectedlocation = $_COOKIE['your-selected-location'];
        echo ("<hr>Your cookie is: $cookieselectedlocation<hr>");
    }
```

I've also tried a direct echo:

```
echo $_COOKIE[ 'your-selected-location' ];
```

With no luck.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Chris

**EDIT: Here's where it gets weirder:
www.site.com/merchant_profile --> Cannot read cookies
site.com/merchant_profile --> CAN read cookies**

Comment: `print_r($_COOKIE);` and see what it outputs.

Comment: Use FF's Net tab (or something like HTTPFox) to verify that the cookie is actually being sent to the server.

Comment: print_r returns: Array ( ) which I guess is an empty array but I can see in Firebug there are at least 3 cookies set in the root

Comment: Question.  The cookie is saved at site.com/ and I'm working in site.com/merchant_directories  does that make a difference?

Comment: Hi @ChrisCummings did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

When you set a cookie with setcookie() it's not in the $_COOKIE array until the next page load, but it still makes it to the browser.

Comment: This cookie was set a few weeks back on a different part of the site.  I also deleted it with Firebug and let the original coding add it back but still can't get it